# JSF 2.0 change datatable row height

Tags: css, jsf

I do not know if there is anything specific with styling JSF datatable but I can not get the row height changed.

Here is my datatable:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myBean.myValue}"
             rowClasses="dt_row"
             var="o">


</h:dataTable>
```

Here is my css dt_row class:

```
.dt_row {
    height: 10px;
}
```

But when the rows is generated the height remains the same no matter what values I specify in my css class.
The source of generated page looks like this and it seems ok:

```
<tr class="dt_row">
```

Any ideas?

Here is my whole table:

```
    <h:dataTable value="#{searchBean.searchResult.concordances}"
                 styleClass="table"
                 var="concordance">

        <h:column>
            <pre>#{concordance.left}</pre>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <pre style="color: blue;">#{concordance.middle}</pre>
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <pre>#{concordance.right}</pre>
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
```

Comment: answer updated hope it works for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML `tr` doesn't have height attribute. The height can be defined for `td`.

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>DataTable Row Height Sample</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            table {
                width: 200px;
            }
            table tr {
                color: darkorange;
            }
            table tr td {
                height: 80px;
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="myForm">
            <h1>Show data</h1>
            <!-- check that I'm using styleClass, not rowClass -->
            <h:dataTable id="dataTable" var="data" value="#{datatableBean.lstData}"
                border="1" styleClass="table">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="ID" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{data.id}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Value" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{data.value}" />
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</ui:composition>
```

UPDATE:

I've tested this in Chrome 18 and IE 9. I'll include images of the table changing only the td height:

height: 30px;

[image]

height: 50px;

[image]

height: 10px;

[image]

As you can see, the row height changes. Maybe you're testing in Internet Explorer and your style changes are not updated. To change its behavior, go to **Tools** / **Internet Options** then in the section **Browsing History** select **Settings** a popup will appear, in the section **Temporary Internet Files** check the first option *Every time I visit the webpage* now select OK to close the popup and OK again to close the Internet Options, update your website and you can see the changes.

Comment: It does not work. I tried it already. If I specify the column style classes I only can make column height bigger. It is generated about 55px so I can 56px or more but not less. What I need is make less px on the height.

Comment: I'm not saying that you must specify the column class. If you check the CSS, I define the style for table, table row (table tr) and table cell (table tr td), then only applying the style to the table and let that HTML and CSS do their work.

Comment: I am using chrome, and firefox. The colors changes to orange and its ok. But the height is not going less. I change css even througth firebug the height remains the same except if I specify more than 55px.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis I've tried using 100px and it worked for me. It will be better if you update yout actual code and see how are you trying to do it

Comment: Could you include your code? I will compare it to mine. Because I updated my code, recompiled, it does not work for me... :( The height is not getting less than 55px. I can not get 10px to work 20px and so on.

Comment: @PauliusMatulionis my code is already there, but I will post all of it, hope it works for you

Comment: That would be great, I need to see all table of yours.

Comment: I see. There is some differences. Maybe there is any influence that your table is wrapped within ui:composition tag? And mine is not? The color change but thats it, nothing more. I have updated my question.

Comment: Can you add the styleClass you're using like I did?

Comment: I am using your style class for testing.

Comment: OK, now I see, I removed <pre> tags and the height now changes. It is another question how to solve this height issue if the <pre> tag is inside <td>...

Answer (score 0):

Try  this :

```
<p:dataTable id="table" >
<p:column id="id" headerText="#{message.label_id}" style="height:10px">
</p:column>
```